# How can we Order the list using IN() using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I would like to know, how can we ordered the list using order by in MySQL.
below are the statement

```
SELECT info.* From p_all,resinfo 
WHERE (p_all.id = info.id ) AND 
    p_all.id IN (21,10,42,84,234,15,251) AND 
    p_all.table_type = 'price' AND p_all.room_type='d' AND 
    p_all.year = '2012'
order by p_all.room_type='d'
```

Please provide me some information, how can we Order the room type (Price) according to Highest to Lowest.

info = stored id and hotel information.
p_all = month table with same id (info) having information of price (table_type), rooms (room_type), year (2012)

Comment: if you have SQL question why do you put line of PHP code? just to obfuscate and make it harder for people to provide an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordering is easy, you simply list the fields you want to order by after the keywords ORDER BY.  You don't make it clear which column actually *contains* the price (you say `room_type` and `table_type` in different places in your question) but assuming the price is in table_type you would use:

```
 ORDER BY p_all.table_type DESC
```

(the DESC, standing for "descending" means the sort will be from highest to lowest).

You'll also have to deal with the fact that you reference `info` as a table in your results but there is no such table included in the SELECT (probably you meant `resinfo`?).

It would be helpful if you showed the original table structures and perhaps a few records from each.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ORDER BY` clause must have what you want to order.

```
SELECT info.* 
FROM   p_all, 
       resinfo 
WHERE  ( p_all.id = info.id ) 
       AND p_all.id IN ( 21, 10, 42, 84, 
                         234, 15, 251 ) 
       AND p_all.table_type = 'price' 
       AND p_all.room_type = 'd' 
       AND p_all.YEAR = '2012' 
ORDER  BY p_all.price DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others, you can't order by a comparison (`p_all.room_type='d'`).  You need to order by actual values.  If you want (`p_all.room_type='d'`) to come first, you could try the following instead?

```
ORDER BY
  (CASE WHEN p_all.room_type='d' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

`From p_all,resinfo` - it's not correct. Use `join` for joining another table. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Also it's not allowed to do any assign in `ORDER BY` clause. For sorting in back direction use  `ASC` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html